# Iterate over multiple files and count multiple strings

Tags: python, file, loops, counter

I want to write a code to open multiple text files and count how many times predefined strings occurs in each file. My desired output it can be a list of the sums of occurrence of each string along the files.

My desired strings are values of a dictionary.

For instance:

```
mi = { "key1": "string1", "key2": "string2", and so on..." }
```

For the purpose to open **a unique file** and  realized my desired count I got the code. Check below:

```
mi = {} #my dictionary
data = open("test.txt", "r").read()
import collections 
od_mi = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(mi.items()))
count_occur = list()

for value in od_mi.values():
    count = data.count(value)
    count_occur.append(count)

lista_keys = []   
for key in od_mi.keys():
    lista_keys.append(key)

dic_final = dict(zip(lista_keys, count_occur))
od_mi_final = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic_final.items()))

print(od_mi_final) #A final dictionary with keys and values with the count of how many times each string occur.
```

My next target is do the same with multiple files. I have a group of text files that are named according a pattern, e.g. "ABC 01.2015.txt ; ABC 02.2015.txt ...".

I made 3 text files as test files, in each one of the files, each string occurs one time. Therefore, in my test run my desired output is a count of 3 for each string.

```
mi = {}
import collections
od_mi = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(mi.items()))
for i in range(2,5):
for value in od_mi.values():
    x = "ABC" + " " + str(i) +".2015.txt"
    data = open(x, "r").read()
    contar = data.count(value)
    count_occur.append(contar)

 print(count_occur)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I realize that my code was overwriting the counting when entered each time in the loop. Therefore, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Counter from the values in your mi dict, then use the intersection between the new Counter dict keys and each line of split words:

```
mi = { "key1": "string1", "key2": "string2"}


import collections
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dict.fromkeys(mi.values(), 0))
for fle in list_of_file_names:
    with open(fle) as f:
        for words in map(str.split, f):
            counts.update(counts.viewkeys() & words)
print(counts)
```

If you are looking for exact matches and you have multiple word phrases to find, your best bet will be a regex with word boundaries:

```
from collections import Counter

import re

patt = re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(v) for v in mi.values()]))
for fle in list_of_file_names:
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in f:
            counts.update(patt.findall(line))
print(counts)
```

You might find that calling  the regex on f.read() presuming the file content fits into memory:

```
with open(fle) as f:
     counts.update(patt.findall(f.read()))
```

The regular `re` module won't work for overlapping matches, if you `pip install [regex][1]` that will catch the overlapping matches once you set the overlapped flag:

```
import regex
import collections
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dict.fromkeys(mi.values(), 0))

patt = regex.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(v) for v in mi.values()]))
for fle in list_of_files:
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in f:
            counts.update(patt.findall(line, overlapped=True))
print(counts)
```

If we change your examples slightly you can see the difference:

```
In [30]: s = "O rótulo contém informações conflitantes sobre a natureza mineral e sintética."

In [31]: mi =  {"RTL. 10": "conflitantes sobre", "RTL. 11": "sobre"}
In [32]: patt = re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(v) for v in mi.values()])) 
In [33]: patt.findall(s)
Out[33]: ['conflitantes sobre']

In [34]: patt = regex.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(v) for v in mi.values()]))

In [35]: patt.findall(s,overlapped=True)
Out[35]: ['conflitantes sobre', 'sobre']
```

Comment: Hello, Padraic! Thank you for your help! I made a test with my original dictionary who has many strings with special characters and for some reason does not work. The final output counts zero for them. But i remade my test files and search only for strings without special characters and your code works great. Can you help to solve the problem with my original set of strings ?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your file content and what you have in your dict values? Also what version of python?

Comment: I use Canopy which use ' Python 2.7.10 | 64-bit | (default, Oct 21 2015, 17:08:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'.  some examples = > "RTL. 10": "O rótulo apresentado está ilegível/incompleto.",  "RTL. 11": "O rótulo contém informações conflitantes sobre a natureza mineral e sintética."

Comment: Are you actually looking for more than just  single words?

Comment: Ah ok, well that is a very different story, you are also matching substrings, i.e  `foo` would match `foobar`?

Comment: I just checked this function and seems to work only for "one" word at time. About your question, the search focus only a predefined strings and shouldn't match variations.

Comment: Yes, it splits the text into individual words but even using your logic with .read is also flawed as it will match partial substrings, to match an exact phrase you will need to use a regex with word boundaries unless you are maybe looking for matching lines not phrases in a line?

Comment: Actually, i'm looking predefined sentences along the lines of each document. The desired goal is count only the occurrence of exactly sentences, not including variants... In your opinion only with regex i can actually do that?

Comment: Yes, calling `"foobar".count("foo") -> 1` so you need the word boundaries, I added an example using a regex

Comment: I need a explanation. For instance: I define my string as: "Não foi apresentado o Anexo V, conforme exigido no artigo 7º, inciso V" and the counter returns it in this way = > 'N\xc3\xa3o foi apresentado o Anexo V, conforme exigido no artigo 7\xc2\xb0, inciso V'. For some reason, my output return zero count for my original strings.

Comment: `N\xc3\xa3o` is the repr representation of the string, `'N\xc3\xa3o' == "Não" -> True`, I have no idea what you are searching for in the string so I cannot say why it does not match anything.  You should add a sample of your file input and the strings you are trying to match to your question, as it is the code does exactly what has been described

Comment: Script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8JeTkdtm-M2dDBEZWxjNTVhY2s ; file1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8JeTkdtm-M2Rl9ZOXFWTlVmQW8 ; file2: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8JeTkdtm-M2b2c0cGVrOE43VVk ; file3: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8JeTkdtm-M2RldiTTZ2Zjlod0U

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to simplify your code:

```
from collections import Counter

mi = {'key1': 'string1', 'key2': 'string2'}
count_occur = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as data_file:
    for data in data_file:
        count_occur.extend([d for d in data.split() if d in mi.values()])

print Counter(count_occur)
```

Then, to process it on multiples files, just loop on a list of files, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

count_occur = []
mi = {'key1': 'string1', 'key2': 'string2'}
files = ["ABC" + " " + str(i) +".2015.txt" for i in range(2,5)]

for file_c in files:
    with open(file_c, "r") as data_file:
        for data in data_file:
            count_occur.extend([d for d in data.split() if d in mi.values()])

print Counter(count_occur)
```

Comment: Hi massiou, thank you for answer. In each case the output was: Counter(). There was not a number in function output, i believe...

Comment: it means that 'count_occur' is empty, is your 'mi' dictionary filled with the requested strings ?

Comment: Yes, sir! My dictionary is filled with all strings. I checked if the count_occur list has something inside and it's empty.

Comment: For some reason the code has the same output as before.

Comment: Just few details, my test files are encoded in UTF-8 and has special characters in it.